# Best practice for generating and displaying thousands of polygons

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am currently working on generating and displaying thousands of polygons on the screen at any one point, I currently do this by defining vertices and creating a mesh using the list of vertices, applying this to a mesh renderer and have it instantiate the object.

This... is fine on my developer PC but on a slow computer or phone, it just doesn't work.

I was mostly hoping if there was any way of rendering lots of small polygons without instantiating an object with a mesh? I was thinking potentially using a shader but I am not the best at writing them! They need to all be static and have the ability to change colours and such?

If the best way would be to use shaders... how would you do it.

Many thanks!

Comment: Are the polygons unique, otherwise duplicating them and doing simple transforms might be another approach? Can you give more details on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is a simulated, pattern of many polygons overlaying a plane, all the polygons are randomly generated on first load, so they won't be the same.

Thousands of dynamic polygons, with individual colour properties that can randomise on a function call.

Sadly having a singular mesh of say triangle, instantiated thousands of times is still almost as strenuous.

Comment: Makes sense, sorry solution I was thinking of didn't make sense then.

Comment: Ah well, i appreciate the effort though, I'm going to investigate possible solutions tonight and from what i am reading creating a shader that can attach to a plane might be a relatively good solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a good solution until i Figure out how to write a shader.

As i am dynamically generating the meshes instead of creating a game object with a mesh renderer and instantiating it. What i am doing is finding all meshes with the same material and using unitys mesh combiner to make a single mesh and then use unitys drawmesh function to avoid instantiating an object.

Using this method i can now render 2.6million triangles at 60FPS on my phone.

Edit:
**Comparison**

Original method:
2.6 million tris, 19,000 objects individual meshes. 50% cpu usage, 3FPS.

Second method:
2.6 million tris, 0 objects, 19,000 instanced meshes using DrawMeshInstanced to batch them. 100% cpu usage 0.4FPS. trying to take advantage of gpu instancing.

Third method:
2.6 million tris, 0 objects, 10 combined meshes and rendering using the DrawMesh method. 13% cpu usage 60+FPS